# Surprising output of a C program when using '*' to multiply

Tags: c

After solving the exercise 5-10 in the K&R:

**Write the program expr, which evaluates a reverse Polish expression from the command line, where each operator or operand is a separate argument. For example, expr 2 3 4 + *   evaluates 2*(3+4).**

there appears to be the problem in expressions with '*' character, even basic ones like: 2 2 *. For some strange reason, '*' is not placed into the *operator* array, while all other characters like '+', '-', '/' normally are. I've isolated the part of the code (while loop) which appears to be wrong. Push function is from Chapter 4 and it is only necessary to compile the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void push(double f);

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a = 0;
    int b;
    char operator[10];

    while (--argc > 0) {
        if (isdigit(*argv[argc]))
            push(atof(argv[argc]));
        else if (*argv[argc]=='+' || *argv[argc]=='-' || *argv[argc]=='*' || *argv[argc]=='/')
            operator[a++] = *argv[argc];
    }
    for (b = 0; b < a; b++)
        printf("%c", operator[b]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

#define MAXVAL 100  /* maximum depth of val stack */

int sp = 0;     /* next free stack position */
double val[MAXVAL]; /* value stack */

/* push: push f onto value stack */
void push(double f)
{
    if (sp < MAXVAL) 
        val[sp++] = f;
    else
        printf("error: stack full, can't push %g\n", f);
}
```

Output

```
[user@machine Desktop]$ ./prog + +
++
[user@machine Desktop]$ ./prog *

[user@machine Desktop]$ ./prog * *

[user@machine Desktop]$ ./prog + / * -
-/+
```

Answer (score 12):

Your shell is interpreting `*` and expanding it.  To the shell, '*' means "match all text", which is why commands like `ls *.c` work.  Type `echo *` and you'll see what I mean.  Put your arguments in single quotes to prevent the shell from interpreting them.

E.g.,

```
./prog '*'
./prog 2 2 '*'
./prog '2' '2' '*'
```

Note that if you put *all* arguments inside quotes, that entire thing will be given to your program as one entry in `argv`, which might not be what you want.

E.g., this command will fill `argv[1]` with the text `2 2 *`, instead of breaking it up into `2`, `2`, and `*` in `argv[1]`, `argv[2]`, and `argv[3]`.

```
./prog '2 2 *'
```

You can also escape individual characters that need escaping with backslash instead of quotes.  Your program will get a literal `*` if you tell the shell `\*`.

E.g.,

```
./prog 2 2 \*
```

This pattern matching is commonly called [globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this.  You saved me a bunch of consternation.